# Program won't return String

Tags: java, string, return

So I've been assigned a problem in my intro to programming class. I did a little research into a way to accomplish this problem and I am able to compile with no errors however one of the stipulations is that I must return a String. This is where I run my head into a brick wall. I've tried a few means to fix the issue but I'm hoping someone here can spot the issue that I've been pulling my hair out over.

```
public class TellSeason {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        season(5 , 12);
    }

    public static String season(int month , int day) {

        if ((month == 9 && day >=16)
            || month == 10
            || month == 11
            || (month == 12 && day <=15)) {
            return ("Fall");
        }
        else if ((month == 12 && day >=16)
                 || month == 1
                 || month == 2
                 ||(month == 3 && day <=15)) {
            return ("Winter");
        }
        else if ((month == 3 && day >=16)
                 || month == 4
                 || month == 5
                 ||(month == 6 && day <=15)) {
            return ("Spring");
        }
        else {
            return("Summer");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the`|`'s for?? That's not reistering for me.

Comment: A program's return value is always an int. Are you sure the requirement isn't just to print a string to stdout?

Comment: || is the 'or' operand. However i was able to complete the question

Comment: @Mureinik A Java program doesn't have a return value.

Comment: @DavidPulse It is a [conditional-or operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.24). Rather elementary.

Comment: And I knew it was an OR, but until I found out that it compiled, according to the poster, i didn't know that was legal

Answer (score 5):

Something like this?

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(season(5 , 12));
}
```

One more hint - you can compare month and day together

```
int idx = month * 100 + day;
if (idx <= 315 || idx >= 1216)
    return ("Winter");

if (idx >= 916) 
    return ("Fall");

if (idx >= 616) 
    return("Summer");

//if (idx >= 316) 
return ("Spring");
```

Answer (score 4):

Two things, first you are not doing anything with the result of your method. Basically, you just call season in your main method, and do nothing with the result.

Secondly, look at the method signature of your main method. It explicitly states that `main` have the return type `void`. Which means, this method can't return anything. You can provide a exit code, by using `System.exit()`, however, this is limited to integer return codes.

I strongly suspect that all you are really after, is the ability to print your result to the console. That is,

```
System.out.println(season(5,12));
```

Comment: Thank you, i guess i was mislead by the wording of the question. It was definitely a DUH! moment

Comment: Your welcome, and trust me, it happens to all of us. If I'd had a pound for ever duh moment i had in programming. I'd be quite rich ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return anything from your main, it is impossible.
But if you want to display your result, `System.out.println` is your method